# How to check if the values of the radio are ticked

Tags: javascript

I would like to check in JavaScript if the value is different from `""` for each one of the radio questions in the radio question, i.e., I would like to check for each radio that there is a ticked answer.

My code:

```
this.current.question = ["", "", "", ""]
```

When responding (between 1 and 4 (response)), `this.current.response` is updated to `this.current.question = ["2", "", "", ""]` (for example, if I click on the second answer).

Then it should go to the next one, but it breaks and I can not check for others. How can I do that?

My whole code:

```
case "question_matricielle_radio":
  console.log("MaRadio");     
  for(var i=1 ;i<=this.current.response.length; i++){ 
   if(this.current.response[verif]==""){
     ok= true;
   }
   verif++;  
 }
 if(ok==true){
   error=true
 }

break;
```

Comment: it's hard to understand what you need without visualization... Please, try to post a minimal working example

Comment: `<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="current.response">
       <ion-item  *ngFor="let modalite of current.modalites ; let i=index">
        <ion-label>{{modalite}}</ion-label>
        <ion-radio color="PFG" value="{{current.valModalites[i]}}"  
        ngControlDefault ></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>`

Comment: in a snippet... edit your question and add, not in the comments